# dataset sorting on full length in jcl without key

Tags: sorting, mainframe, jcl

I want to sort datasets both FB and VB on full length using JCL. I have large number of datasets so I dont want to get file length. is there a way to sort files without feeding in the file length? Sorting should be done on full length of the file. Appreciate our help. Thanks.

Comment: I presume you mean full `length of the record` ???

Comment: A combination of **Rexx** and **ISPF skelton** generation will achieve what you want. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51240074/executing-a-dfsort-using-rexx/51240979#51240979 It covers the ISPF skelton generation

Comment: Thanks Bruce but unfortunately i can't use Rexx here. :(

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  You have a list of datasets, and you want to sort them based on the size of the dataset, correct?  Or based on the record length of the dataset?  What tools do you have available?  JCL in and of itself can't do this; JCL is just a way of invoking other programs to do work for you.

Comment: Kevin, i have thousands of datasets (i'm not sure how many more yet to come) to sort them on their record length. I found it difficult to get record length and build sort control card dynamically. I have JCL and DFSORT utilities.

Comment: Still not clear: are you wanting to sort the list of data sets or sort the data within each data set? And why can you not use Rexx? It is perfect for the job. As an alternative you could use COBOL (or whatever ISPF-supporting language you use in your shop) and ISPF File Tailoring.

Comment: I want to sort the data in each datasets. I want a way to sort the data without feeding in the record length. Rexx is not an acceptable configuration item to deploy into production at my client place.

Comment: Then use COBOL, if that is the preferred language, and use it to connect to ISPF  to execute LISTDSI for each data set and retrieve the LRECL from the output and do the file tailoring for each data set.

Comment: yes.. that's the way to go.. Thank you.

Comment: Is there a fixed area that is common to both FB and the VB records (a minimum area that is always present?)  You could create a SORT CARD based on the LRECL of the file in a step preceding sort.