# Rexx code to change word in jcl and submit

Tags: jcl, rexx

Rexx code to change word in jcl and submit.

There is a JCL code. Requirement is to run the job after doing "C ALL JOB1 JOB2".

Comment: What have you tried ???

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of doing it. I would suggest ISPF skeltons

#### ISPF Skelton

The rexx is

```
ADDRESS TSO "ALLOC DD(OUTSKEL) DS('"OUTSKPDS"') SHR"
job="job2" /* job1 */
'FTOPEN'
'FTINCL SAMPSKEL'
'FTCLOSE LIBRARY(OUTSKEL) NAME('WORKMEM')'
```

The Skeleton becomes

```
//&job. job
```

see [Executing a DFSORT using REXX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51240074/executing-a-dfsort-using-rexx/51240979#51240979)

#### Edit Macro

You could use an edit macro. The rexx

```
'address ispexec edit dataset(my.job.to.edit) macro(mymacro)'
```

and the macro is roughly

```
address isredit 'macro' 
address isredit 'c job1 job2 all'
address isredit 'sub'
```

#### Read/write

Jou could read the JCL line by line, change each line as required and write a new JCL dataset file